# Copying files to var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT

Tags: permissions, webapps, tomcat7

I have installed a web app in  var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT that runs using tomcat7. When i check the file permissions,i see that they are owned by `tomcat7`

How can i copy a file inside `ROOT` and make it `tomcat7` owned. Right now i am logged as `John Doe`

How can i copy files to the var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT and change their ownership to tomcat7?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not in the / directory, you may have to put the absolute path "/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT/styles" in your copy command

Answer (score 0):

To run a command that requiere root privileges you can use 'sudo' in front on your command, ie:

```
> sudo cp /home/myhome/file.txt /other/destiny/file.txt
```

Then, to change the owner:

```
> sudo chown myuser /directory/file.txt
```

You can find basic bash commands [here](https://www.maketecheasier.com/basic-bash-command-for-new-linux-users/)

Comment: I am trying this sudo cp /home/qubit/stage/custom.css var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT/styles and getting  `cp: cannot create regular file ‘var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT/styles’: No such file or directory
`